# Bind a readonly DependencyProperty to another readonly DependencyProperty

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a class that contains a readonly DependencyProperty. From this class, I want to bind to the readonly `DependencyProperty` to another readonly `DepenendencyProperty` of another class (create binding from code).

Is there a possibility to do this? SetBinding() seems not to have a overload that takes a `DependencyPropertyKey` as a parameter? Neither seems the `BindingOperations`-class to provide such functionality.

The question can also be formulated: **Can I create a binding for a readonly `DependencyProperty` if I have the `DependencyPropertyKey`?**

Comment: How is this supposed to work? If both sides are readonly not even OneWay should work in any case, no?

Comment: @H.B. No, since I have the key of the read only DependencyProperty (the DependencyPropertyKey), from the perspective of my class it is not readonly. Only for the outside of the class. Something like the private setter of a CLR-Property - it is accessable from the inside of the class but for other classes it is a read only property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertykey.aspx

Comment: I see; somehow i doubt that it can be done, you could easily register a property-changed-callback though and set the value manually.

Comment: @H.B. I doubt also, but maybe someone knows a way. The PropertyChangedCallback is not really an option because it is on the opposite end of the problem. I could do it with DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged, but as far as I remember this leads very quickly to a memory leak if I don't unregister, and if possible I want to avoid such unregister-code. It makes the code more error prone.

Comment: Are you using DependencyProperty for your business objects? This is not meant to be the way to go, they are really just for gui objects.

Comment: @MikeKulls: No business objects, rather composite-controls.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but wouldn't it be enough to introduce a new DP that acts as a proxy for binding both DPs ?

Comment: @Alex Maker: A DP that is not read only? In this case, the advantange of the read only state is lost. Or have I missunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: @HCL: Never mind, I just realized that it wouldn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible because the `FrameworkElement.SetBinding` method only accepts a `DependencyProperty` as its first parameter. It would have been great if it would also accept a `DependencyPropertyKey` instead. Because the key isn't visible outside the class, it would still be read-only outside the class, but from within the class you could use it for a binding. Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Any good suggestions on how to implement this?

One could try to implement a private RW dependency property, bind the original RO to it, and in RW's callback modify the exposing RO. But this sounds like a hack. Any better options?